# Calculator Transforming Coulomb units freezes unexpletedly

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

> ```
>     internal class Program
>     {
>         static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             double result = 0;
>             Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Physics calculator!");
>             Console.WriteLine("Please choose one of the following options");
>             Console.WriteLine("1.Unit Conversions");
>             Console.WriteLine();
>             Console.WriteLine("What is the current form of the number you are trying to convert?");
>             Console.WriteLine("1.Coulomb");
>             Console.WriteLine("2.mCoulomb");
>             Console.WriteLine("3.μCoulomb");
>             Console.WriteLine("4.nCoulomb");
>             Console.WriteLine("5.pCoulomb");
>             string answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
>             double answerbase = 0;
>             double answerpow = 0;
>             switch (answer1)
>             {
>                 case "1":
>                     Console.WriteLine("Please continue to the next part");
>                     answerbase = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
>                     break;
>                 case "2":
>                     Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number: ");
>                     answerbase = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
>                     break;
>                 case "3":
>                     Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number: ");
>                     answerbase = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
>                     break;
>                 case "4":
>                     Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number: ");
>                     answerbase = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
>                     break;
>                 case "5":
>                     Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number: ");
>                     answerbase = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
>                     break;
>                 default:
>                     Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid option!");
>                     break;
>             }
>             Console.WriteLine("In which for would you like to convert your number?");
>             Console.WriteLine("Choose one of the following options");
>             Console.WriteLine("1.Coulomb");
>             Console.WriteLine("2.mCoulomb");
>             Console.WriteLine("3.μCoulomb");
>             Console.WriteLine("4.nCoulomb");
>             Console.WriteLine("5.pCoulomb");
>             string answer2 = Console.ReadLine();
>             //Console.WriteLine("Please input your number");
>             //double answer3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
>             double resultconversion = 0;
>             while (answer1 == "1")
>             {
>                 if (answer1 == answer2)
>                 {
>                     Console.WriteLine("No conversion neeeded!");
>                 }
>                 else if (answer1 != answer2)
>                 {
>                     switch (answer2)
>                     {
>                         case "2":
>                             answerpow = 10 ^ -3;
>                             resultconversion = Math.Pow(answerbase, answerpow);
>                             break;
>                         case "3":
>                             answerpow = 10 ^ -6;
>                             resultconversion = Math.Pow(answerbase, answerpow);
>                             break;
>                         case "4":
>                             answerpow = 10 ^ -9;
>                             resultconversion = Math.Pow(answerbase, answerpow);
>
>                             break;
>                         case "5":
>                             answerpow = 10 ^ -12;
>                             resultconversion = Math.Pow(answerbase, answerpow);
>                             break;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>                 while(answer1 == "2") 
>                 {
>                     if (answer1 == answer2)
>                     {
>                         Console.WriteLine("No conversion needed");
>                     }
>                     else if (answer1 != answer2)
>
>                     switch (answer2) //line 107
>                     {
>                         case "1":
>                             answerpow = 10 ^ 3;
>                             resultconversion = answerbase/(10 ^ 3);
>                             break;
>                         case "3":
>                             answerpow = 10 ^ 6;
>                             resultconversion = Math.Pow(answerbase, answerpow);
>                             break;
>                         case "4":
>                             answerpow = 10 ^ 9;
>                             resultconversion = Math.Pow(answerbase, answerpow);
>                             break;
>                         case "5":
>                             answerpow = 10 ^ 12;
>                             resultconversion = Math.Pow(answerbase, answerpow);
>                             break;
>                     }
>                       
>                 }
>             Console.WriteLine($"The result in an int form: {answerbase}^{answerpow}");
>             Console.WriteLine($"The number {answerbase} is raised to the power of {answerpow}");
>             Console.WriteLine("The result in decimal for: " + resultconversion);
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

> The problem that I face is that when I reach line 107 my code freezes and nothing happens. I am not sure what's happening. Please note that the code is incomplete and the working functions as of right  now  are only the first and half of the second. I am a beginner and I would appreciate if you would not critisise me for not discovering the problem.

> I added a while loop so for each answer specific things would happen. But inside  the second while loop something seems to be broken inside the first switch case at line 107. When I input the form of the current number as mCoulomb and the form I am trying to convert it to Coulomb the program just freezes.

Comment: The `^` is not a power operator - it's a bit-wise [Exclusive OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-) operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple, you have a `while` loop on `answer1`  but you are not modifying it anywhere in your code. and that is the reason it is becoming an infinite loop. you can either add a `break` at the end of each while loop (you need to check this first). or modify the `answer1`  so that it may come out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Vivek's answer is correct as to what's happening in your program. You should mark his answer as correct.

I'm posting this as a way for you to see how this code can get written.

```
string unit = "Coulomb";
var factors = new[]
{
    new { name = "", magnitude = 0 },
    new { name = "m", magnitude = -3 },
    new { name = "μ", magnitude = -6 },
    new { name = "n", magnitude = -9 },
    new { name = "p", magnitude = -12 },
};

string[] header1 = new string[] { "Welcome to the Physics calculator!", "Please choose one of the following options", "1.Unit Conversions", "", "What is the current form of the number you are trying to convert?", };
string[] header2 = new string[] { "In which for would you like to convert your number?", "Choose one of the following options", };

int GetFactorIndex(string[] header)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, header.Concat(factors.Select((x, n) => $"{n + 1}. {x.name}{unit}"))));
    return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;
}

int index1 = GetFactorIndex(header1);
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number: ");
double value = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int index2 = GetFactorIndex(header1);

int magnitude = factors[index1].magnitude - factors[index2].magnitude;

double factor = Math.Pow(10.0, magnitude);
double answer = value * factor;

Console.WriteLine($"The number {value} {factors[index1].name}{unit} is multiplied by {factor}");
Console.WriteLine($"The result in value of: {answer} {factors[index2].name}{unit}");
```

That's it. I think it is working correctly. Let me know if there are any issues you discover.